# How to write a Parser that validates its input against a predicate and otherwise fails

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I want to write a Parser that produces some data structure and validates its consistency by running a predicate on it. In case the predicate returns `false` the parser should return a custom `Error` object (as opposed to a `Failure`, since this can be achieved by `^?`).

I am looking for some operator on parser that can achieve that.
For example, let's say that I want to parse a list of integers and check that they are distinct. I would like to have something like this:

```
import util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  val number: Parser[Int] = """\d+""".r ^^ {_.toInt }
  val list = repsep(number, ",") ^!(checkDistinct, "numbers have to be unique")

  def checkDistinct(numbers: List[Int]) = (numbers.length == numbers.distinct.length)
}
```

The `^!` in the code above is what I am looking for. How can I validate a parser output and return a useful error message if it does not validate?

Comment: Please ask a question; the more focused, the better.

Comment: Thanks, I added a question at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^?` accepts an error message generator, `commit` converts a `Failure` to an `Error`:

```
val list = commit {
  repsep(number, ",") ^? (
    { case numbers if checkDistinct(numbers) => true},
    _ => "numbers have to be unique" )
}
```

Comment: I've commented before that this does not work in some cases, but it seems to have been an error in my test code.

Check out also my own solution below who actually pimps up Parser with an ^! operator.

Comment: If you do list | "keyword" (replacing repSep by rep1Sep obviously), it will fail to parse when input is keyword. I think you want to commit only after you are sure you have a list.

Comment: @didierd I find your answer more comprehensive.

Comment: No problem, but surprised that your code is tested ok by the OP. Sure it will fail with Error, but as I see it , the point of Error is that you may stop the exploration of alternatives _sometimes_; if all non success are errors, alternatives are not explored when you succeed, and they are not when you don't so there is no point in having alternatives in the first place. I feel I may be missing something there.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this would be to use the [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern to add the `^!` operator to `Parser[List[T]]` (the return type of `repsep`). Define an implicit def, then import it into scope when you need to use it:

```
class ParserWithMyExtras[T](val parser:Parser[List[T]]){
  def ^!(predicate:List[T]=>Boolean, errorMessage:String) = {...}
}

implicit def augmentParser[T](parser:Parser[List[T]]) = 
  new ParserWithMyExtras(parser)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Parsers.commit` transforms Failure to Error. 
So a first step would be

```
commit(p ^?(condition, message))
```

However this would give an error if p gives a failure, which I suppose is not what you want, you want an error only when p succeeds and then the check fails.
So you should rather do

```
p into {result => commit(success(result) ^? (condition,message))}
```

That may sound rather contrived, you may also implement directly, just copy the implementation of ^? replacing failure with an error.

Finally you should probably do as suggested by Dylan and add the operator. If you want to do it outside of your grammar (`Parsers`) , I think you will need a mixin:

```
trait PimpedParsers { self: Parsers => 
   implicit def ...
}
```

Otherwise you cannot easily refer to (single) `Parser`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) implementation:

```
implicit def validatingParsers[T](parser: Parser[T]) = new {
  def ^!(predicate: T => Boolean, error: => String) = Parser { in =>
    parser(in) match {
      case s @Success(result, sin) => predicate(result) match {
        case true => s
        case false => Error(error, sin)   // <--
      }
      case e @NoSuccess(_, _) => e
    }
  }
}
```

The new operator `^!` transforms the parser on the left to a new parser that applies the predicate.

One important thing to note is the `sin` on the line marked with `<--`. Because the Error that is eventually returned by Scala's parser library is the one in the latest position in the input, it is crucial to pass `sin` in that line instead of `in`, as `sin` represents the point where the inner parser completed its own parsing.

If we passed `in` instead of `sin`, the error that would eventually be reported could be the latest failure that happened during the parsing of the inner rule (which we know that eventually succeeded if we got to that line).